# drupal module config ignore doesn't ignore block

Tags: drupal, drupal-modules

I have installed drupal module config ignore but I don't get what is missing beacuse it doesn't work.
I have set config ignore settings to ignore block.block.countries but it still is being listed on config synchronization
[image]

[image]

Comment: My drupal version is 9.1.3 and module config ignore version is 8.x-2.3

Comment: maybe some old configs. What happens if you delete the block.block.countries.yml file from config/sync folder and export again?

Comment: We moved on with another approach. Thank you for your help @danielarend